# Error 0x8007000D - edit file metadata of a mp4 music file

Tags: file-management, windows-10, media-manager, music-recognition, mp4

I am searching for a program that allows me to edit the file details of a mp4 music file.

Here is an image of the error message and the current details of the media file;
[image]

Through the property window I have enabled full control on the security tab.
I have also tried using the MediaMonkey and ID3-Tagit programs.

Is there a program that will allow me to edit the file details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mp3Tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/) is capable of editing MP4 audio, and other formats, metadata.